# What's the relationship between javascript vm and WebAssembly abstract machine?

Tags: javascript, virtual-machine, webassembly

What is the relationship between javascript virtual machine and WebAssembly abstract machine?

As I know that WebAssembly directly using javascript virtual machine instead of building a new vm. But I see "WebAssembly abstract machine" on the official website, so what is the relationship between these two stuffs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JavaScript "virtual machine" is an implementation detail of practical implementations, nothing that is defined by the language.

The WebAssembly "abstract machine" is a specification device to define the semantics of Wasm execution. It isn't an implementation but a formal concept.

At least in browsers, Wasm and JS are implemented as part of a single VM. However, standalone implementations of Wasm exist as well.

Comment: Can I considered that the WebAssembly binary format was executed based on the javascript virtual machine? Something like the last produced x86-64 assembly code (decoding from the binary format) was executed by underlying javascript vm?

Comment: The VM contains several compilers, for both JS and Wasm. They usually share parts of their backends, if that's what you're asking.